# Workaround to Read Response Body on Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Apparently, Chrome extension's API does not allow an extension to read the response body.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487422

My extension needs to read the response body to get the data from the page.

I tried...

```
  chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener((details) => {
       fetch(details.url)
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(res => responseFunction(res))
       .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, { urls: ["*://*.url.com/*"], types: ["xmlhttprequest"] }
  );
```

But that, of course, is an infinite loop.

I've set up a proxy server on a different machine, but that seems silly and is very inefficient.

Has anyone else tackled this problem?

Comment: The only built-in method is the debugger API: [getResponseBody](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/Network/#method-getResponseBody). Don't ask me, I haven't used it, look around for existing answers or extensions that implement it.

Comment: Thank you, I've come across that.  But this will be a commercial extension so a chrome dev API won't be useful

Comment: debugger API is not a dev API and it's available in Stable builds. Its main nuisance, however, is a big warning on the top of all pages it's connected to.

Comment: @wOxxOm, re "only"; what about proxy?

Comment: Proxy itself is an external thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just use some additional header in your request as a sign that you don't need to execute your listener on the request you have created:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener((details) => {
  if (!details.requestHeaders.find(({ name }) => name === 'some_flag')) {
    fetch(details.url, {
      headers: {
        some_flag: true,
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => responseFunction(res))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}, { urls: ["*://*.url.com/*"], types: ["xmlhttprequest"] });
```